# Format a pandas dataframe based on value type with unknown columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a website that takes excel sheets, converts it to a pandas dataframe, sending it back back with some calculations and formatting.  So the user supplies the decimals and dataframes:

```
decimals = 2
df = pd.DataFrame([["a", 1], ["b", 2.2]], columns=["name", "value"])
```

And then some arbitrary trailing zeros/rouding position that the result needs to be sent back with:

```
name    value
a    1.00
b    2.20
```

I made it this far, until I started hitting type issues:

```
if decimals:
    pandas.options.display.float_format = f"{{:.{decimals}f}}".format
    df = df.astype(float)
```

but then of course `df["name"]` is going to be unable to convert:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'a'
```

If I knew ahead of it I could just use `df.format()` but in this situation they might upload arbitrary matrices comprised of strings, floats, or integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either check the current type, and convert only for types you want (any numeric type or only floats?) or you can convert everything that's convertible (easier to ask forgiveness than permission):

```py
for col in df.columns:
    try:
        df[col] = df[col].astype(float)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks, I can even move the formatting to an apply now! `df[col].astype(float).apply(f"{{:.{decimals}f}}".format)`